# Creating a Feature to determine popularity

Tags: recommender-system, feature-engineering

I am building a recommendation system where I have multiple categories. I would like to  Know how popular a product is in each category. For that, I am considering probability as one factor. For example, I have 3 categories ($C1$,$C2$,$C3$) so, I am calculating:

(Number of times a particular item in C1 is purchased)/total number of items purchased from C1)

This gives me the probability of each item within a category. Apart from that, I am also trying to consider:

(Total number of times an item has been purchased/total number of times it has been viewed)

However, I do not understand how to use the purchase/view ratio with probability. Apart from that, what another factors can I conclude?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your shoes into business people and communicate with people from that department on regular basis, trying to understand what the business's needs are. In e-commerce your second metric is *Conversion Rate* and is defined as:

```
CR = Orders/Views*
```

Please note there that there are two variations of *Views*. One that comes from *Product List Page (aka PLP)* that is mostly know as *Impression*, or the one comes from *Product Detail Page(aka PDP)* is where the user actually lands on the product detail page. The latter is more common in the *CR* calculation.

Your first one i.e. the popularity, that somehow I liked, can be used. Only be careful that it is going to be affected by number of items available in that category.

**In general,** I find it useful to think about edge cases when coming up with new measures and to see whether the resultant is desirable. What do I mean by edge cases, let's take your popularity score, by your definition, for example. Imagine the following two scenarios:

- popularity item 1 = 1/2 (very limited items in this category where item 1 is)
- popularity item 2 = 1000/2000 (large number of items in this category where item 2 is)

What you see here looks quite normal by the original definition from mathematics perspective. However, what it means from recommendation/business perspective that you have similar scores from two items from two different categories. Here the business may jump in and say looks we have a lot of more assortments in the category where item 2 is and often items in this category are in the warehouse or have faster delivery etc. etc., then we prefer our products from there to be recommended first. This is the point you realize that while results seem reasonable, at least according to the popularity definition, falls short on certain aspects.

**Other ideas:** I noticed you are leaning towards using multiple scores. That is a great idea. Having multiple factors may catches these corners and address multiple business needs at the same time. Like having both *CR* and *popularity*. Or may think of each item's profit contribution to the business and take that into consideration. Imagine you have a score in place that gives equal chances of recommending an iPhone or Wireless Mouse, however iPhone contribute way more to the business (it is more profitable), then you may want to push for that factor too. You may also like to look at *Impression* I mentioned if it is available from your tracking. Item's *rating*, *delivery*, *Add_To_Cart*, *Wish_List*, or *Time_Spent_on_Item* are other things to think about. Check [this post](https://www.mediasearchgroup.com/blog/amazon-seo-tactics-2018/) to get some other ideas how things are roughly done in Amazon. Hope these help.